# Membership.GetUser with profile properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

Im trying to get all users with a username i search for with properties.

```
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.FindUsersByName(txtSearchName.Text + "%");
datalist1.DataSource = users;
datalist1.DataBind();

//In the datalist
<asp:Label ID="UserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
```

The code above works I can type any username from the database and it will show. 
but I also need all the profile properties that i have specified in the webconfig like firstname, lastname etc.

Comment: You will need to make additional calls to get the profile data.  I would iterate over the returned list of users, querying for the additional information, and then store likely store it in an array/dictionary for recall later.

Answer (score 0):

```
var profiles = ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles(ProfileAuthenticationOption.Authenticated)
datalist1.DataSource = profiles;
datalist1.DataBind();


<asp:Label ID="UserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="LastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the profile properties through the profile provider class

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(userName);
var firstName = profile["FirstName"] as string;
var lastName = profile["LastName"] as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always handled this in a business logic layer. You'd need to create a custom type to extend your profile attributes and add a `UserAccount` property:

```
    public static Profile GetProfile() {
        Profile profile = null;
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            var user = Membership.Provider.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, false);
            if (user != null) {
                // an AD user who is already authed
                profile = ReferralsData.GetProfilesByProviderKey(user.UserName) ?? new Profile();
                profile.UserAccount = user;
            }
        }
        return profile;
    }
```